# Bash script Insert variable into file at specific line

Tags: xml, bash

I have an xml file and somewhere in that file is this tag:

`</Locations>`

In my bash script I have a variable that contains a string a bit like this

`<Location id="1" label="hello world"/>`

How can I insert that variable into the xml file above the `</Locations>` tag?

And how can I insert multiple lines above that same tag with a loop?

Thank you.

Comment: You can do it with `sed`. Although it would probably be better to use a tool like `xmlstarlet` to manipulate XML.

Comment: You would have to replace the existing opening `^<Location.*/>$` tag with sed. Much better done with an xml-"aware" utility. (and you need to decide whether it is `</Locations>` or `</Location>` (non-plural)

Comment: I tried this `sed -i "/</Locations>/$newTag" "$file"` but no luck.

@DavidC.Rankin There is a section with the <Locations/> tag, plural, and within that I place the <Location/> singular tags.

I'd rather not use xmlstarlet because I want to share this script with us and the less dependencies it has the better.

Comment: David, if you really want to do it, it's `sed -i "/^</Locations>$/i $yourvar"`

Comment: What that `sed` command does is find the line that contains `"</Locations>"` alone and the inserts the contents of `$yourvar` as a new line above it. You may need to adjust due to the `...ions` (and no `s`) ordering in your xmlfile. `xmlstartlet` is just a small utility (like `sed`, but specifically made for modifying xml files...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you!